# Writing 'ON' Events for Physics Engine

Tags: c++, oop, physics

I'm writing a 2D physics engine in OOP. And I was wondering how can I create a sort of "onTouchStart" or "onTouchEnd" event system for physical objects in space?

And yes I know there is Box2D and others, but I want to do something in house since the game is going to do very basic collision checking. Plus I see this as a way to learn something new.

Anyway, I have this code....

```
void phPhysics::step(float delta)
{
    int objectCount = m_objects.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < objectCount; ++i)
    {
        phPhysicsObject* obj = m_objects.at(i);

        /* Update positon of the object. */
        obj->update(delta);

        if(!obj->isSleep())
            checkForCollisions(obj);
    }
}

void phPhysics::checkForCollisions(phPhysicsObject* object)
{
    int objectCount = m_objects.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < objectCount; ++i)
    {
        phPhysicsObject* obj = m_objects.at(i);

        if(object == obj)
            continue;

        if(isColliding(object, obj))
            obj->onTouchStart(object);
    }
}
```

As you can see I have onTouchStart event, but this of course is going to continuously trigger on "onTouchStart". How do I have this only trigger 'once' on collision and once on touch end? I thought of doing a array of objects touching each other, but I don't know if that works well.

Comment: How do you plan to solve your collisions ?

Comment: Simple AABB, nothing much too it. The only thing I can see being a problem is bullet detection atm, but again, I'm learning as I go.

Comment: I don't speak about collision detection, but collsion solving. How will you make your objects go away one from each other (to not have the collision anymore) ?

I'm asking this because you often do this by applying impulses to your objects (you can see it as a force applied over a very short time, or an immediate change in velocity) but you don't seem to be doing this kind of stuff (and that might change the way you could / should handle your "onTouchStart" stuff)

Comment: Sorry, I missed read your comment. I wont be doing much collision response. I'm working on a very basic top down shooter. So moving objects away from each other isn't needed at this point. Perhaps one day I decide to go full blown 2D game engine w/ Lua or something I'll put a lot more thought or simply switch to Box2D, but again. I only use the tools I need.

Comment: Plus at least getting my feet wet in this area seems like a plus. ;)

Comment: Ok so if I understand correctly, you want to detect collisions between "player ship", "enemy ships" and bullets thrown by both. If the collisions are purely related to gameplay (i.e for a shoot em up, a bullet touches a ship it loses health point), they have, imho, to be handled by the game logic, and not the objects themselves. I can clarify and develop a bit in an answer if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

I think it works well. In `phPhysicsObject` you can have an `array` of objects (or their `id` if they have one, to save memory), then everytime `onTouchStart` is called, you can check if the object is already in it, if not, then you have a new object colliding. If it is, then you stop, because the function was already called for that object. And then `onTouchEnd` would remove the object from the array.